# Connecting to Remote Docker Provider via TLS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ssl, amazon-ec2, airflow

I'm trying to set up Apache Airflow, using the DockerOperator, and running into a TLS error.  I've reproduced the error in python with the following code:

```
import docker
tls_config = docker.tls.TLSConfig(ca_cert='./ca.pem', client_cert=('./cert.pem', './key.pem'), verify=True)
client = docker.APIClient(base_url='https://****.com:2375', tls=tls_config)
client.version()
```

i get the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='****.com', port=2375): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1.35/version (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')))
```

Any ideas why this is happening?  When I manually run the request to get the docker version via curl, it works:

`curl --cert cert.pem --key key.pem https://****:2375/version`
returns

```
{"Platform":{"Name":""},"Components":[{"Name":"Engine","Version":"20.10.4","Details":{"ApiVersion":"1.41","Arch":"amd64","BuildTime":"2021-03-29T18:55:03.000000000+00:00","Experimental":"false","GitCommit":"363e9a8","GoVersion":"go1.15.8","KernelVersion":"4.14.232-177.418.amzn2.x86_64","MinAPIVersion":"1.12","Os":"linux"}},{"Name":"containerd","Version":"1.4.4","Details":{"GitCommit":"05f951a3781f4f2c1911b05e61c160e9c30eaa8e"}},{"Name":"runc","Version":"1.0.0-rc93","Details":{"GitCommit":"12644e614e25b05da6fd08a38ffa0cfe1903fdec"}},{"Name":"docker-init","Version":"0.19.0","Details":{"GitCommit":"de40ad0"}}],"Version":"20.10.4","ApiVersion":"1.41","MinAPIVersion":"1.12","GitCommit":"363e9a8","GoVersion":"go1.15.8","Os":"linux","Arch":"amd64","KernelVersion":"4.14.232-177.418.amzn2.x86_64","BuildTime":"2021-03-29T18:55:03.000000000+00:00"}
```

Comment: What about `tls_config = docker.tls.TLSConfig(client_cert=('./cert.pem', './key.pem'), verify='./ca.pem')`?

Comment: the same issue. but when i say `verify=False` it works. but i need it to verify.

Comment: I think verify=True is for public certificates, not self-signed. Also why your curl does not include `ca.pem`?

Comment: i don't believe my cert is not self signed, it was issued through cloudflare, and it's for a wildcard domain. :-/. i might just abandon using TLS altogether here.

Comment: I see. You can wait a  bit more. Someone may provide more insights, as it seems you have valid public cert, thus its interesting why it does not work.

Comment: i also pulled the `verify=True` parameter from the source for the DockerOperator (which you can see here): https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.3/_modules/airflow/operators/docker_operator.html#DockerOperator

Comment: update, not a solution but i'm just connecting to docker via TCP now, just in a private network in AWS and it seems to be fine.